# Pointer and copy constructor: strange behavior?

Tags: c++, runtime-error

The following program prints 969 when compiled using g++ 4.8.3 in windows 7 (64 bit).

Uncommenting the declaration of `Y` copy constructor, the program produces a segmentation fault. An analysis of addresses shows that `a` and `a.value` always have the same address.

In former case (comment) `a` and `arg1` are allocated in different locations, in the latter (no comment) they share the same location, so the content 969 is wrongly dereferenced as pointer.

Can anyone explain why the behavior changes? It seems using parameter by value in former case (comment) and parameter by reference in latter (no comment).

```
#include <iostream>

struct X
{  double value; };

struct Y {
  // Uncommenting copy constructor, myFunc should behavior in same way
  // Y(const Y&);
  X *ptr;
};

void myFunc(Y arg1) { std::cout << arg1.ptr->value << std::endl; }

typedef void (*XLFUNC) (void*);

int main() {
  X a;
  a.value = 969;
  XLFUNC xlFunc = (XLFUNC)myFunc;
  xlFunc(&a);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a good argument against the use of `void*`. You are taking the address of an `X`, treating it as a `Y`, dereferencing a member that doesn't exist... to call this Undefined Behavior is putting it politely.

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined. You can't expect anything from a code that exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: Btw, gcc 4.8.3 is *old*. There is already gcc 7.2.